# docker compose up working fine but browser showing site can't be reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

**docker-compose up** showing this:

```
Recreating tutorial_product-service_1 ...
Recreating tutorial_product-service_1 ... done
Attaching to tutorial_product-service_1
product-service_1  |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
product-service_1  |  * Restarting with stat
product-service_1  |  * Debugger is active!
product-service_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 192-693-276
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
 product-service:
  container_name: tutorial_product-service_1
  build: ./product
  volumes:
   - ./product:/usr/src/app
  ports:
   - 5002:80
```

I have installed docker on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and its IP is : http://18.225.37.175

But when I run http://18.225.37.175:5002/
it shows me site can not be reached.

Any help?

Comment: How are your inbound rules: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to allow traffic on port `5002` in the [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) configured for the instance.